# Open Twitter app to make tweet

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I’m trying to open the Twitter app to make a tweet. Here’s what I have:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("Twitter"));
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Did you just ask the same question twice?

Comment: no the thing was, i think that the solution was diferent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See which one would suit you best:

ShareStatusTask - for sharing status

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharestatustask(v=vs.105).aspx

ShareLinkTask - for sharing link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharelinktask(v=vs.105).aspx

ShareMediaTask -for sharing media

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharemediatask(v=vs.105).aspx