# How to open facebook app to post and image on wp8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I like to know if there is the chance to open the facebook app to post an image with a comment I have this:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:post"));
```

There is the chance to send the image as some parameter or something like that?

Comment: This sounds very similar to the [one you just asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667255/open-twitter-app-to-make-tweet)...

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/a/19378464/1230188

Comment: yes that was i get in the first place the path to work, but i need something diferent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those are the classes to share on wp8 development

ShareStatusTask - for sharing status

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharestatustask(v=vs.105).aspx

ShareMediaTask -for sharing media

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharemediatask(v=vs.105).aspx